# CSS issue with a Background Image

Tags: css, background-image, z-index

I'm trying to add a background image to my site-header. Part of the image should be covered by the main-content.

It is positioned correctly however even though I've added z-index, the main content doesn't cover the background image.

[Here is the website.](http://frenchegg.com)

Why would that be?

Thanks!

Edit:

If you look on the right side you will see the brown egg is not covered by the main content. You can still see part of it.

Here is some code:

```
.header-navigation.back {
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-top:-6px;
    border:none;
display:block; height:137px; width:1171px; padding:0px; outline:none; text-indent:-9999px;
background-image:url('http://frenchegg.com/images/backmenu.png');
}
```

and here is the main content that should cover the image:

```
.main-content {
    z-index:99;
    position:relative;
    padding:1em 0 8.5em 0;
    background:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Please share some code or consider making a fiddle, rather than only pointing links to your websites, as if your website is no more, this question will be of no use to future visitors

Comment: It looks good in my browser.

Comment: You can give as many z-index as you want... The `main-content` position doesn't coincide. `main-content` is far below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please add the `overflow:hidden` css to the `header-wrap` class

```
.header-wrap {
  ...
  overflow: hidden
  ...
}
```

and it should look good.

---

For the log in issue:

remove the `z-index: 99999` from the class `.bann`

and add this css to the class `tooltip-wrap`

```
sorry something went wrong
```

Thanks

Comment: Ah, i apologize. i misunderstood. I shall fix it

Comment: It works perfectly! However if you click on the "Sign In" you should see a login form. The form is hidden though. How could I fix this?

Comment: yes, i noticed this. working on it.

Comment: @LouisG.Talbot in line 1752 of your styles.css you have `right:0` please remove this. and in line 1338 add `display:none` to `tooltip-wrap`

Comment: It works! However, something weird happens. If you try to write something in the form, you will see the backmenu.png picture and the header going up.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could just reduce the height of the header-navigation.back rule to 100px rather than mess with z-index.

Comment: I'd rather cover it instead since on a mobile version the eggs are shown completely.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the bann class to :

```
.bann {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 101.5%;
    z-index: 99999;
    margin-left: 12px;
}
```

after that it seems ok ... check it and inform me of the result;

I tested the code above with firebug ;)